# What are some differences between a Shallow Copy and Deep Copy?

Tags: python, deep-copy

i am not getting the difference between shallow copy and deep copy.
copy.copy and copy.deepcopy() gives the exact same output.
Their memory location seems to be different than the other but the reference address has confused me a lot.

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) out.

Answer (score 2):

The deep copy will also copy *nested* containers. Perhaps the best way to demonstrate is by showing an example where the shallow copy is insufficient:

```
>>> import copy
>>> L1 = []
>>> L2 = [L1]
>>> L3 = copy.copy(L2)
```

Now L3 is a shallow copy of L2. Modifications to L2 itself will not be mirrored:

```
>>> L2.append("x")
>>> L2
[[], 'x']
>>> L3
[[]]
```

However, modifications to the nested list L1 will be mirrored in both:

```
>>> L1.append("y")
>>> L2
[['y'], 'x']
>>> L3
[['y']]
```

If we had used `copy.deepcopy` instead of `copy.copy` when creating L3, then the nested list L1 would also have been copied. The result would be that L3 would still be `[[]]` in the final example, and L3 and L2 would be truly disconnected containers.

Answer (score 0):

A shallow copy creates a new object with the properties copied from the source. A deep copy creates a new object with properties that are themselves new objects based on the properties of the source.

If the source only contains primitive values, there won't be any difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy. The difference appears when the source contains properties that are collections or complex objects. Consider the following:

```py
source = [['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Here we have a source object that is an array which contains an array. If we perform a shallow copy, the new object will contain a reference to the same array:

```py
target = copy.copy(source)

target[0][0] = 'd'
print(source)
print(target)

# Output:
# [['d', 'b', 'c']]
# [['d', 'b', 'c']]
```

As you see, the inner array of both `source` and `target` point to the same array. As such, anything you do in `target` will affect the contents of `source` and vice versa.

By contrast, a deep copy doesn't just copy references, it recursively copies values of the nested objects and collections:

```py
target = copy.deepcopy(source)

target[0][0] = 'd'
print(source)
print(target)

# Output:
# [['a', 'b', 'c']]
# [['d', 'b', 'c']]
```

The contents if the inner array in `target` is no longer the same as the inner array in `source`. They are two different arrays that happen to contain the same items.

This doesn't just apply to arrays. Dictionaries, class objects, and other collections will behave similarly under `copy` and `deepcopy`.

Comment: terminology point: python doesn't have "primitives". Also, those are *lists* not arrays. "class object", I presume, you means *instances of classes*, but *every object is an instance of a class in Python*. Because class objets, e.g. `int`, `str`, or `class Foo: pass` and `Foo` don't actually get copied at all with `copy.deepcopy`

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple program:

```py
l = [[2], [4]]
lc = l.copy()  # shallow copy

lc[0][0] = 1

print(lc)   # [[1], [4]] no surprises here
print(l)    # [[1], [4]] because shallow copy
```

so even though you modified only `lc`, values (lists) inside outer list still refer to same anonymous inner lists.

Would you use `copy.deepcopy()` instead to copy `l` to new list, then it would recursively copy values of any nested data structures, and modifying `lc` would not change the original list values in `l`